# ImportError: No module named Qsci while running ninja-ide

Tags: python, qscintilla

I am trying to install and run ninja-ide http://ninja-ide.org/home/

However when I try to run ninja-ide I am facing this error

```
ImportError: No module named Qsci
```

I have been trying to install ninja-ide whole night.

I tried everything installing from source, installing using apt-get dependencies mentioned on various blogs.

I installed everything. SIP, PyQt4, Qscintilla, all kinds of dependencies.

I made symlinks for python installation folder in `/usr/local/include/python2.7` as python was installed in `/usr/include/python2.7`.

I even copied the Qsci folder from `/usr/include/qt4` to `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4` and `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4`.

I am now tired of installing everything. I still can't figure out why it gives me the

```
ImportError: No module named Qsci
```

I have been scouring Google and Stack Overflow the whole night.

Answer (score 8):

You need to install:
python-qscintilla2

Also, the version that requires that, is the version still on development, not an official release.

Answer (score 2):

For Qt4 use:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyqt4 python-qscintilla2
```

For Qt5 use:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyqt5 python-pyqt5.qsci
```

See all available packages here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qscintilla2

Answer (score 1):

install this

```
sudo apt-get install python-qscintilla2
```